# What is considered as good practice to terminate a program, if starting requirements are not met

Tags: java, exit

I have an initializing thread in my application, that aggregates and sequentially runs several subthreads (check necessary directories, check if xml files are available, etc). I want my program to safely terminate, if the requierements are not met.

What approach should be used here?

- Should each subthread terminate the program, if he finds his requirements are not met (e.g. in java `System.exit(0);`) I think that's not a good practice.
- Another idea I have is that each thread sets a boolean in a global map. The map is than checked after the initialzing thread (but that would be a problem if the subthread 2 depends on subthread 1). The benefit would be that the application could terminate 'softly'

**QUESTION**

So, what is considered as good practice to terminate a program (smaller-medium project about 6 kLOC), if starting requirements are not met. The concept should include (at least) the possibility of printing detailed error messages.

---

Since the question was too broad. I'm limiting it to java to reduce it's broadness. To make it more complex I'd would also be happy about concepts that include parallelism.

Comment: Sry for my unclear wording. I replaced 'process' with 'thread'.

Comment: So to clarify, you're spawning new threads?

Comment: It is not about threads, they run sequential, parallelism is no concern here. I just did that to encapsulate the different initializing tasks in differnt objects.

Comment: Feel free to add more suiting tags to the question. `exit` was the only one that came to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends per language, but I suppose a good way to do it would be to simply run a pre-check program that checks if everything is OK. At the end it generates an answer, and if the answer is yes your main program would run. In other words, your pre-check is what actually calls your main program.

Comment: My idea tended in this direction, too.

Answer (score 1):

> Should each subprocess terminate the program, if he finds his
>   requierements are not met (e.g. in java `System.exit(0);`) I think
>   that's not a good practice.

How would the subprocess terminate the main program? I assume you're talking about actual OS processes. Those could terminate *themselves*, and the main program could be monitoring all the subprocesses for terminations. When one exits with an unsuccessful code (`1`), the main program can terminate itself.

Comment: I adjusted the questin and replaced the word process. I did not mean an actual OS process. It's all one program, one can abstract from the os here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just calling a sequence of subroutines, have each subroutine return `true` if it succeeded and `false` if it fails.

The caller of these routines can inspect the result, and terminate the program gracefully if any of the routines fails.

For example

```
bool b = true; // Indicates success of initialization sequence

if (b && !(b = initFoo()))
    ; // Log your failure

if (b && !(b = initBar()))
    ; // Log your failure
```

But I agree that having a given subroutine terminate the application is not a good choice. Leave that decision in the hands of the caller.

Answer (score 0):

`System.exit(0)` is traditionally used for successful termination. So anything other than `0` is probably a better choice.

But why not have each "subprocess" throw an exception that is handled by the main program? Setting a global has code smell.

Comment: Hmm, what I learned was that a program should terminate itself, i.e. reach the end of `main()`

Comment: I think it would work without a static global variable as well, If you had some kind of checking object (simple map wrapper) that you could pass around. After wards you could check the internal state of the object, print corresponding error message or terminate the program by don't starting it.

Comment: It's a fully reasonable for a program to provide an exit code. Even still, the main program can catch exceptions thrown by the "subprocess" (by which I think you mean something other than OS process), and exit gracefully.

Comment: It certainly would work with an object such as you described. But it seems clunky (my subjective opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Have the sub-process exit and check the return with java.lang.Process.exitValue(). The sub-processes exit value should be specific about the error.

```
private static final int REQUIREMENT_1_NOT_MET = 1;
private static final int REQUIREMENT_2_NOT_MET = 2;

if (! checkRequirement1Conditions())
    System.exit(REQUIREMENT_1_NOT_MET);
if (! checkRequirement2Conditions())
    System.exit(REQUIREMENT_2_NOT_MET);
```

If the process is designed to continue running (i.e., only terminates when conditions are not met), you may need to ignore that IllegalThreadStateException that is thrown.